# How to export DataGrid data to Outlook

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, datagrid, outlook

**My goal**: I want to add certain items/rows that's added into my DataGrid, to display in my Outlook's `HTMLBody` once I create a new Email.

**My Issue**: I have no idea where to begin and how I would be able to achieve my goal. So I would like to get some pointers and ideas from anyone willing to give them.

Here are some of the basic coding that (I think) will help me.

- I can insert my items that I want into my datagrid from my WCF service

  ```
  private async void btnSupplierAddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      using (MKCServiceClient service = new MKCServiceClient())
      {
          var selectedId = (lbxSupplierSearchItems.SelectedItem as ViewQuoteList).Id;

      QuoteItemList qd = new QuoteItemList()
      {
          Id = selectedId,
      };

      var items = await service.GetListOfQuoteItemsAsync(qd);
      foreach (var item in items)
          dgSupplier.Items.Add(new ViewQuoteItemList
          {
              CustomerRFQ = item.CustomerRFQ,
              Item = item.Item,
              Material = item.Material,
              Description = item.Description,
              AdditionalInformation = item.AdditionalInformation,
              Quantity = item.Quantity
          });
  }
  ```

  *No need to see my WCF coding as everything works fine*
- My method where I use the Microsoft Outlook Interop reference and where I create my `MailItem`

  ```
  private void SendRFQRequest()
  {
      OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
      Outlook.MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

      mailItem.Recipients.Add(lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content.ToString());
      mailItem.Subject = "Quote Request";

      mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test Body</body></html>";

      mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;

      mailItem.Display(false);
  }

  //Where I call my SendRFQRequest method
  private void btnSupplierSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      SendRFQRequest();
  }
  ```
- My references

  `using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;`

  `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

So now that you've seen my coding and what i've done so far, what do you think would be the best way to approach my goal?

Comment: "*No need to see my WCF coding as everything works fine*" - Then why tag the question with WCF?

Comment: If i'm using it in my code why shouldn't I put a tag on it here? If you have nothing constructive to post to my question why post such a useless comment?

Comment: Comments are for requesting clarification - it doesn't make sense (to me) to tag a question with something that is not part of the problem, and since you said the WCF worked fine, it's clearly not part of the problem.  I don't see it as unconstructive or useless.  If you didn't like it, don't respond or flag it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right and you just want to transform your DataGrid to html maybe that could help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23640/How-to-send-DataGridView-contents-by-email

The idea is to iterate over your DataGrid columns and rows and transform them to html `<table>`,`<th>`,`<tr>`,`<td>` tags (or choose your favorite way to implement a table). You could then parameterize your `SendRFQRequest` like `SendRFQRequest(string content)` and set it to your html body.